# MVC 6 .NET Nhibernate DNX core 5.0 - Not available

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nhibernate, fluent

Im add to project Fluent and Fluent NHibernate and I have on Fluently:
Project.DNX Core 5.0 - Not available.

```
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
```

I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember NHibernate works only now only on `dnx451` framework. If you are compiling it for Windows you can remove `dnxcore50` from frameworks in project.json

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit project.json you can put,

```
#if DNX451
//whatever code is giving issue with DNX Core 5.0
#endif
```

You can use this anywhere even when defining namespaces, e.g. what I recently used in my asp.net project for using Xml was;

```
#if DNX451
using System.Xml;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a while to see if there are plans to bring [NHibernate](https://github.com/nhibernate) to the new, cross-platform .NET Core and here is what it looks like:

- It doesn't seem that that anyone is working on it at the moment or consider it important,
- [NHibernate have some dependencies](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/0dOV9TTPpsg) on libraries that at the moment aren't compatible with .NET Core. Even if they were, it would require some breaking changes to make NHibernate itself compatible,
- There doesn't seem to be much activity going on in the NHibernate project.

If I understand it correctly, it means that if you want to target Linux/Mac platforms with your MVC6 application, and you wanted to use NHibernate with it, hold no breath as it won't happen.

In this situation, [Entity Framework Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) seems to me like the natural alternative to use and learn. It's open source, actively developed, with good opinions among developers, and designed with MVC 6+ in mind.